# What are disadvantages of using a Bridge pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

I could not find anything on the Internet and would appreciate your answers.

Thank you

Comment: One potential disadvantage is complexity. A bridge design is overkill for scenarios where the inheritance tree will be limited and will not explode. Separation of interface and implementation on the scale of bridge pattern needs more duct tape to make it work than just implementing the inheritance hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Some of the points mentioned below can be termed as disadvantages of Bridge Pattern

1. Increased complexity due to over use of HAS-A principle
2. Interfaces with only single implementation
3. Multiple indirection

Comment: Ok thank you! What is the disadvantage of 2. interfacing with only a single implementation? What exactly does 3. multiple indirection mean?

Comment: 2. If the number of interfaces are limited then it doesn't sweat a breath but if you have an exploded set of interfaces with minimal or only one implementation it becomes hard to manage.

Comment: 3. Multiple Indirection: Since Bridge Pattern relies on HAS-A i.e. composition, it could chain multiple method calls to perform an operation leading to multiple stack operations and slight latency